# Google Speech/NAudio has a large delay if the speaker is far away from the microphone

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, naudio, google-speech-api

I'm doing speech to text with the google speech api and NAudio (with the NAudio WaveInEvent class). Like this: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize?hl=en (C# example for "Performing streaming speech recognition on an audio stream")

If the speaking person is close to the microphone everything works nice and fast. But if the speaking person is far away from the microphone his first 3-5 words aren't recognized. After that the other words are recognized very well. (So it can't be a generall problem with the distance) More like an adaption problem to the distance or maybe NAudio isn't recording with 100% volume input.

Any ideas to that problem?

Edit: Here is the code that was asked for:

```
static async Task<object> StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(int seconds)
{
    if (NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No microphone!");
        return -1;
    }
    var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
    var streamingCall = speech.StreamingRecognize();
    // Write the initial request with the config.
    await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
        new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
        {
            StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
            {
                Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                {
                    Encoding =
                    RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                    SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                    LanguageCode = "en",
                },
                InterimResults = true,
            }
        });
    // Print responses as they arrive.
    Task printResponses = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(
            default(CancellationToken)))
        {
            foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream
                .Current.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    // Read from the microphone and stream to API.
    object writeLock = new object();
    bool writeMore = true;
    var waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent();
    waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
    waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 1);
    waveIn.DataAvailable +=
        (object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs args) =>
        {
            lock (writeLock)
            {
                if (!writeMore) return;
                streamingCall.WriteAsync(
                    new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                    {
                        AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString
                            .CopyFrom(args.Buffer, 0, args.BytesRecorded)
                    }).Wait();
            }
        };
    waveIn.StartRecording();
    Console.WriteLine("Speak now.");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
    // Stop recording and shut down.
    waveIn.StopRecording();
    lock (writeLock) writeMore = false;
    await streamingCall.WriteCompleteAsync();
    await printResponses;
    return 0;
}
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how the things work. The engines use adaptation to sound levels, if the levels too low, they will simply miss first words and will start recognition only after adaptation. The accuracy will be lower than expected.

To solve this - use more advanced microphone array which will track audio source like Respeaker or Matrix and probably use a custom speech recognition system which is more robust to quick audio level changes. It will be cheaper than Google API too.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Speech API has [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices) for it to work optimally this includes:

> The recognizer is designed to ignore background voices and noise without additional noise-canceling. However, for optimal results, position the microphone as close to the user as possible, particularly when background noise is present.